# Angular2 Firebase phone number authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

Can anyone tell me the complete code for Angular2 Firebase phone number authentication? I am not getting it from Google.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official documentation of Authentication with Firebase with a Phone Number [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth).

And if you are using the AngularFire2 library, here is David East's answer on [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/981):

> We decided to not wrap auth methods and instead provide a way to inject Firebase Auth instead, once we upgrade to 4.0 they will be available for injection.

Comment: Hi Hamed. Is the *quote from David East* seen in an official post/vid? It would be better if you could provide a link for it as well. :)

Comment: @AL. here is the link to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/981